# Not able to import the .jsx file

Tags: jquery, reactjs

> Below is my import code:-

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import Header from '../src/components/Header';
import MortgageCalculator from '../src/components/MortgageCalculator'
import Employees from '../src/components/Emp'
import Employee from '../src/components/Employee'
class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (

           <div>
               <Header title="React WbPack"/>
               <MortgageCalculator principal="200000" years="30" rate="5"/>

               <Employee/>
           </div>

        );
    }
}
```

> import Employee from '../src/components/Employee' is my .jsx file for
>   the same route but error is coming as "not able to import".What can be
>   the issue?
>
> My webpack.config.js is:-

```
  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app-client.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using 
`import Employee from '../src/components/Employee.jsx'` if the component is default exported or use `import { Employee } from '../src/components/Employee.jsx'` if not exported by default

Comment: now Employee.jsx no need to write because in config file now wrote as :- resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

Answer (score 0):

> Its start working as a changed my config file as:-

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app-client.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    }, resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,  // Match both .js and .jsx
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```